# Default System Table in BonitaSoft BPMN

Tags: bpmn, bonita

I am new to BonitaSoft BPMN . Please clarify if BonitaSoft has default system tables as Activiti BPMN ? Where does the information gets stored if we run a process in Bonita. Please help.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not seem to be the 1st stop for this non-coding question. See http://community.bonitasoft.com/resources/faq#question

Answer (score 2):

Bonita has two databases:
1. bonita_journal
2. bonita_history

If you start a process it will store the data in bonita_journal db, and close the process the data stores in bonita_history.

Both the dbs has 69 tables:

```
+--------------------------+
| Tables_in_bonita_journal |
+--------------------------+
| BN_ABSTR_ACT             |
| BN_ABSTR_ACT_ITDESC      |
| BN_ACTOR_DEF             |
| BN_ACT_CAND              |
| BN_ACT_DEF               |
| BN_ACT_INST              |
| BN_ACT_PERFORMERS        |
| BN_ATTACH_DEF            |
| BN_ATTS_INST             |
| BN_ATTS_METADATA         |
| BN_CATEGORY              |
| BN_COMMENTS              |
| BN_CON_DEF               |
| BN_CON_PARAM_            |
| BN_DATAF_DEF             |
| BN_ENTITY_RULE           |
| BN_EVENTS                |
| BN_EVENT_PROC_DEF_       |
| BN_EXCEPTION_RULE        |
| BN_GROUP                 |
| BN_GROUP_RULE            |
| BN_IEI_                  |
| BN_IE_DEF                |
| BN_INCOMP_EVENTS         |
| BN_INST_ACTUSERS         |
| BN_INST_USERS            |
| BN_ITER_DESCR            |
| BN_LOB                   |
| BN_MEMBERSHIP            |
| BN_MEMBERSHIP_RULE       |
| BN_METADATA              |
| BN_OEI_                  |
| BN_OE_DEF                |
| BN_PI_STATE_UPD          |
| BN_PROC_CAT              |
| BN_PROC_DEF              |
| BN_PROC_INST             |
| BN_PROC_INST_CHILD       |
| BN_PROC_INST_VARS        |
| BN_PROC_METADATA         |
| BN_PROC_SUBPROC          |
| BN_PROFILE_METADATA      |
| BN_PVM_ARGDESCR          |
| BN_PVM_DESCR             |
| BN_PVM_EXEC              |
| BN_PVM_OPERATION         |
| BN_ROLE                  |
| BN_ROLE_RULE             |
| BN_RULE                  |
| BN_RULETYPE_POLICY       |
| BN_STATE_UPD             |
| BN_SUBFLOW_PARAM_DEF     |
| BN_TASK_ASS_UPD          |
| BN_TA_UPD_CAND           |
| BN_TRANS_DEF             |
| BN_TRANS_STATES          |
| BN_USER                  |
| BN_USER_MEMBERSHIP       |
| BN_USER_PROFILE_METADATA |
| BN_USER_RULE             |
| BN_VAR                   |
| BN_VAR_UPDATE            |
| BN_WEB_CASE              |
| BN_WEB_TOKEN             |
| ENTRY_NODES              |
| EXIT_NODES               |
| INCOMING_TR              |
| OTHER_NODES              |
| OUTGOING_TR              |
```

Comment: Note that this is the table structure for Bonita BPM 5. Bonita BPM 6 only use one database and archive table have a prefix in their name.

Answer (score 0):

Bonita BPM use a H2 database to store the system data.
You can find more information in the documentation :
http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/database-configuration-1#h2default

It is possible to change the database if you prefer another type of database.

Answer (score -1):

There are two main "apps" whe you say **Bonita**. `Bonita BPM Studio` and `Bonita Portal`. In current version, 6.5.X, the default database used by the Bonita BPM Studio is the H2.

If you want to change the database, just modify two files under `<bonita-folder>\workspace\server_configuration\tomcat_conf`:

- ...\Catalina\localhost\bonita.xml
- ...\bitronix-resources.properties

Comment: You should not change the database of the development environment (Studio and its Tomcat).

Using another database than H2 is only for production,and you don't go on production with the Studio. Bonitasoft provides 3 bundles for production (without studio): one with Tomcat, one with Jboss, and another one to be integrated in your java web application server.

Comment: Well, I think this is your opinion. In my company we use **SQL Server 2008** as a development environment and works well, besides the better performance and the data tests, that are very much easier than the ones made on h2 database.

Comment: But it means you are doing the tests with the Studio. You should do them with a bundle.

Comment: We got three environments: development/test (in studio), pre-production (a bundle) and production (a bundle). So, I don't think my answer above is incorrect.

Comment: But you are using SQL Server with the Studio ?

Comment: Yes. It's exactly what I mean with _In my company we use SQL Server 2008 as a development environment and works well_

Comment: ok. just note that is not good practice to change the database of the Studio ;-)